# How to change my second pickerView's array based on the selection from the 1st pickerView

Tags: swift, xcode, pickerview

I have two pickerViews i.e. `pickerView1 = car_make`, `pickerView2 = car_model`.

If I select `car_make = Kia`, I want pickerView2 to show the array of models `[Rio, Venga, Ceed]`, and if I selected `car_make=Ford` from pickerView1, then I want pickerView2 to show the model array `[Mondeo, Ka, Focus]`.

I've tried editing the `didSelectRow` function, and have managed

```
if pickerView == carMakePicker {
    if carMake[row] == "Kia"{
        // How to assign new array?
    }
}
```

but then I don't know how to assign the new array to carModelPicker

Comment: Can you show us a bit more of your code? What's in your dataSource? How do you store the car brands and the car models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
struct Car {
    let name:String
    let models:[String]
}
```

Then fill the array like

```
cars = [Car(name: "ppp", models: ["1","2","3"])]
```

For number rows of `picker1` be `cars.count` and for `picker2` be `cars[selected].models.count`

Where

```
var selected = 0 // suppose you will show models of first car initially
```

When the user clicks `didSelect` do

```
if pickerView == picker1 {
   selected = row
   picker2.reloadAllComponents()  
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes so much more sense and now works. The only thing now is when I select a different car_Make, pickerView2 now focusses on the bottom entry rather than the top, but that's the next thing for me to look at more closely